# LinearLayout didn't work with checkboxes

Tags: java, android

i try to make a list made of checkboxes.
I set my layout to LinearLayout (horizontal) and put on it a lot of checkboxes.
I would like everyone to be in a different line.

Unfortunately "horizontal" does not work.

So it looks to me:

[image]

Comment: Look up horizontal vs vertical

Comment: I misplaced the orientation icons horizontal and vertical, should be the reverse icons, anyway works and thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does exactly what you told it to. You wanted them to lay vertically:

```
View 1
View 2
View 3
View 4
...
```

But you requested horizontally:

```
View 1 View 2 View 3 View 4 ...
```

So set the orientation to vertical:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```